# Mental calmness during timed test taking

Tags: graduate-school, exams

I am preparing for a timed post-graduate test (for example, GRE, GMAT etc.). I get hung-up on questions where I don't immediately find a path, and then beat myself over not doing it fast enough while I am still on the question. This further increases my time on the question by taking focus away from the problem at hand.

Additionally, the above gets compounded with thoughts of inadequacy- "I am dumb" etc. etc. This adds to the time guilt and takes away from thinking clearly about problem solving.

If you've had a similar experience, what did you do during test taking to overcome it?

Comment: Considered counselling?  No insult intended.  Cognitive therapy would work well to remedy this.  Otherwise, the only suggestion I have is practice, practice, practice, so that seeds of self-doubt are harder to plant.

Comment: How much does this get in your way?  A fellow student in grad school went straight to the emergency room with chest pain and suspected heart attack, from a qualifying exam.  I'm asking because the what-to-do-about-it depends on how it is affecting you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest getting used to self-proctoring practice exams within a certain time limit. Keep at it until you figure out how to determine when it is fruitful to skip a question. Come back to it later when you have an ah-ha moment or finish the exam. As for worrying about spending too much time or self-depreciating yourself, try to minimize it. Remember your successes. Take time to build up your confidence both inside and outside academia and strive to do the best you can do.

Think of every difficulty as a chance to be humbled, and use that outlook to find wisdom in the experience. In grad school, I'm sure you'll encounter this same feeling just by speaking with people whom are your senior.

Comment: In fact you can. You can even mark a question left empty to more easily find it later

Comment: @ThreeDiag I stand corrected about whether you can skip a question and come back on the computerized GRE, thanks! I couldn't remember and I had thought it would mess up the branching algorithm behind the computerized adaptive test, but perhaps they just treat a skip as "no new information, give a question on the same level."

Comment: Honestly I have no clue about that. Are you somewhat involved with the working of the gre behind the scene? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: @ThreeDiag I've studied the stats behind tests like the GRE, but my main info on exactly how it works is my memory of taking it before grad school. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done the GRE with a decent score.

Here is the deal: you ought to realize that the type of difficulty you are facing now are the real test in there. No one cares if you know triangles, but can you conquer the stress of the test? That's what you will be training.

So, here are some tips. You can score greatly on the gre by skipping some questions and, actually, it is almost mandatory that you guess some. Why? Because answers for which you don't know the solution (or a reasonable path to the solution) are subtracting time from questions you know how to do or for which you can work out a solution in a reasonable time.

So, do practice :

- Assessing whether you know the answer right away after reading
- Assessing whether you can reasonably work it out in a short time. This is the hardest bit, and it's a bit trying to answer and a bit guesstimating.
- If you can't, can you reduce the answer pool by a couple of patently absurd answers ? If you can, then guess and move on. This is a crucial skill: a question that you get right half of the time is worth half a point. Don't think it is worth half a point on average, think that is worth half a point, period. In fact, by saving time and energy for other questions it is worth much more than that.
- if you can't, skip it and don't waste other time on it (unless you have spare time at the end).
- Find a strategy that works for you to minimize aggressive thoughts: it might be de escalating with a recurring mental joke ("Well, I guess I **will** be a baker in the end, at least dad will be happy!"), it might be just pushing back ("Not now brain, test!"), it might be focusing on the content ("Sure, brain, but what's the sum of the angles of triangle again?"). If you find this hard it's because it is. But remember : this is a skill just like multiplication, you have to train that too and you can and by training it will improve!

Let me add that these kind of thoughts you are having are rather normal, but depending on the severity of your aggressive thoughts you might want to have some counseling.